# Questions with no attempt whatsoever get upvoted and questions with effort unanswered?

Tags: discussion

I am getting frustrated by the questions on the home feed getting upvoted which have no effort put in to them.
Its as if the way to get upvotes is to ask a question from a textbook and add "How do I do this?"

The last two questions I have posted, I have attempted several times myself, almost pulling my hair out! (not actually...maybe once), and not even a comment or a push, which is what I asked for. NOT the entire thing done for me.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

This type of post must be on here but it is not coming up in "Questions that may have been answered".

Could someone point out what is wrong with:

[What "tools" are available when determining the convergence of a functional series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522774/what-tools-are-available-when-determining-the-convergence-of-a-functional-seri)

[Computing the basis of a subspace of matrices with the given nullspace.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520831/computing-the-basis-of-a-subspace)

so I can no longer make these mistakes.

Comment: i agree with you...i don't understand how people vote up this kind of questions or even answer it (but on the other hand i don't think this kind of questions get more then one or two votes most of the time)...also the voting behaviour  on answers  became somehow strange to me, there are many excellent answers the last time having just a single or even zero upvotes.

Comment: bear in mind that, among the top ten highest voted questions, we find a number that are also closed, and this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real  Meaning that there may not be much correlation between the worth of a question and its votes

Comment: hahahahaha. The batman equation...... *sigh*

Comment: +1 for the OP and for tired's comment.